# SONATA_TYPE_MODEL_AUTOCOMPLETE does not work

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

with sonata Admin bundle dev-master, I've relationship like Many Vote can be linked to only One PollingStation as the number of the PollingStation entities are so plenty (over 40000) I've to use  SONATA_TYPE_MODEL_AUTOCOMPLETE (propose any best way if you think it exists) but after setting up the configureFormFields like in the [official documentation](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/form_types.html), I get the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: read_only

$builder->setAttribute('minimum_input_length', $options['minimum_input_length']);
    $builder->setAttribute('items_per_page', $options['items_per_page']);
    $builder->setAttribute('req_param_name_page_number', $options['req_param_name_page_number']);
    $builder->setAttribute('disabled', $options['disabled'] || $options['read_only']);
    $builder->setAttribute('to_string_callback', $options['to_string_callback']);
```

Comment: did you get any solution for this problem ? cos i have the same issue

Comment: update your vendor the issue has been fixed long time ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been fixed by the sonata project contributors long time ago so just do:

```
composer udpate
```

Comment: i tried this solution but i got this error 

`Problem 1
    - Installation request for sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle[dev-master].
    - sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle dev-master requires sonata-project/admin-bundle 3.x-dev@dev -> no matching package found.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.
`

Comment: Try to update the bundle itself: composer update sonata-project/admin-bundle

Comment: `- The requested package sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle == 2.3.3.0 could not be found.
    - Can only install one of: sonata-project/block-bundle[2.3.9, 2.2.13].
    - Can only install one of: sonata-project/block-bundle[2.3.9, 2.2.13].
    - Can only install one of: sonata-project/block-bundle[2.3.9, 2.2.13]....`

Comment: which Symfony version are you using ?

Comment: i am using symfony 2.8

Comment: composer require sonata-project/admin-bundle:3.x-dev@dev

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109932/discussion-between-anass-boukalane-and-saint-cyr-mapouka).